# Laravel Belongsto many relationship with additional column

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have been facing a problem in my project. I have a belongsto many relation with additional field.

For example I have two table User and Social table and a pivot table named social_user. Here my user model is

```
public function socialinfos() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Social::class)->withPivot('id')->whereNull('deleted_at');
}
```

And my social_user table is

```
Schema::create('social_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->bigInteger('user_id');
    $table->string('social_id')->nullable();
    $table->string('url')->nullable();
});
```

Here I my belongs to many relation has an additional url field which is submitted by user. When I want to add this information in my database it is not working well. It shows error

```
Array to string conversion (SQL: insert into `social_user` (`social_id`, `url`, `user_id`) values (2, jahid56, 9))
```

Here is What I tried

```
$user = Auth::user();
$speakers  = $request->get('provider'); // related ids
$pivotData = array_fill(0, count($speakers), ['url' => $request->get('social')]);
$syncData  = array_combine($speakers, $pivotData);

if ($request->get('provider')) {
    $user->socialinfos()->sync($syncData);
} else {
    $user->socialinfos()->sync([]);
}
```

Please help me solving this

Comment: what $request->get('social') have ? can you show ?

Comment: @HasanTıngır here what is what my `$request->get('social')` have `["habib", "habib12"]`

Comment: What's the result of `dd($syncData);`?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have this:

Social <--> Social-User['id', 'social_id', 'user_id', 'url'] <--> User

In order to attach a Social to User you need could do this:

```
Auth::user()->socialInfos()->attach($social_id, ['url' => 'facebokk.com/user']);
```